# Iot Stack logo addition?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred

When looking at accounts on my profile, we have a generic logo.  Lots of other stacks have cool designs.

Is anyone accepting design concepts for an IoT logo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're absolutely right that many sites have nicer logos - and actually full themes - than we do.  The reason is because we are still in beta.  As it stands currently, beta sites don't have a full site theme, and all follow the theme mentioned in [this post on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126185/new-stack-exchange-beta-theme).

There is, however, [a tentative change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/333472) coming, in which there is supposed to be a fairly major overhaul of the themes.  There's also a [little-noticed comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes#comment1002231_307922) by Jon Ericson which suggests that beta sites may be able to work out their own themes once the changes have been rolled out.

So by and large, the answer is, *we* can't change this; we have to wait on the Stack Exchange team.  Hopefully, they'll work something out.  Probably in about [6-8 weeks.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/333472)

For more information, you can browse the [beta-sites](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beta-sites) and [design](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) tags on [meta.stackexchange.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbeta-sites%5D%2C+%5Bdesign%5D)